# CPU usage is too high with cmatrix on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I installed the cmatrix with brew on Mac(OS X 10.11.1).
The CPU usage goes to 190% when I run cmatrix and fullscreen the terminal.[image]

Comment: fyi each core is counted as 100%. Looks to me like you are using nearly 2 cores of a 4 core cpu. If you don't like it don't run it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you've actually asked a question, but to answer the implicit question “why is the CPU usage so high?” the first step would be for you to define “too high”.

`cmatrix` drives a very complex animation as fast as it can, which necessarily consumes CPU. If you profile Terminal you'll find that it spends about 100% CPU processing the output from `cmatrix`, and the other approximately 100% rendering the display. Since `cmatrix` *is designed to* make the terminal work, by painting the entire display every 1/30th of a second, it is unsurprising that it would keep Terminal busy most of the time. Terminal is actually showing its mettle by splitting the work onto two CPUs so that it can run at a higher frame-rate.